# What's my favourite flower?

Tags: riddle, visual

I was going to make an order at a florists for a bunch of my favourite flowers.

However, I got a bump on the head and have forgotten what type of flower is my favourite.

Whenever I try and think of its name, I see these 3 images.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Can you help me remember what my favourite flower is?

Comment: I would hazard that these are never sold in bunches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your favorite flower:

> Petunia?

First Hint:

> Dogs and cats are pets

Second:

> Thanks @jafe. The second picture is "Tun[e]"

Third:

> The red state is Iowa, which is abbreviated 'IA'

Comment: The middle image is probably a rot13[ghar]?

Comment: There may be overlap in the letters